# Can not activate the log-bin

Tags: mysql, innodb, binary-log

I have a database that uses the InnoDB engine on all his tables, running on a Windows Server 2008 r2 64bit in a VM farm. The policies of my organization promotes that every server has to have a replication that can run in the case of disaster in the primary (a DRP). So, in order to achieve that, I tried to activate the log-bin, (to deploy a slave server), I checked the CPU and Memory usage and everything seemed to be normal, but the log file wasn't created, also the DB started reject lots of connections and the app started to act odd. As soon as I deactivated the log-bin everything went back to normal (immediately).

The next time I try to activate the log;

What can I do to  ensure the log-bin is activated, besides uncomment the Log-bin= line?
What parameters from the Data Base can be monitored to see what is wrong or need tuning?

Comment: I think you left something out; "The next time I try to activate the log;" *what*?

Comment: The next time I try to activate the log;

What can I do to ensure the log-bin is activated, besides uncomment the Log-bin= line?What parameters from the Data Base can be monitored to see what is wrong or need tuning?

Comment: Ah, the blank line between "the log;" and "What can I do," as well as the capital W in "What," made it look like there was supposed to be something in the middle which had been left out.  Got it now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I have a very busy database, I still don't know exactly why but these settings made the log bin work

```
log-bin=
binlog-format = ROW
transaction-isolation = READ-UNCOMMITTED
```